# Not clear on how this javascript code works.

Tags: javascript

I am wondering how this foreach loop is working (see the reset function). 
I'm guessing I can call somePropertyManagerArray.reset(); and it will execute a foreach loop over it. I'm not grasping what goes on in the loop.

```
PropertiesManager = function() {
    this.controls = {};
    this.controlNames = [];
};
PropertiesManager.prototype = {
    // code block removed //
    reset: function(selectedControls) {
        var controls = this.controls;
        **Array.forEach(selectedControls || this.controlNames, function(control) {
            controls[control].reset();
        });**
    }
};
```

Comment: It will loop through `selected controls` if it exists, or `this.controlNames` otherwise. Then for each control, it gets the corresponding entry in the `controls` dictionary and calls its own reset function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me re-write that function in a much more verbose way:

```
reset: function(selectedControls) {
    var controls = this.controls;

    var arrayToIterate;
    if (selectedControls) {
      arrayToIterate = selectedControls;
    } else {
      arrayToIterate = this.controlNames;
    }

    Array.forEach(arrayToIterate, function(control) {
        controls[control].reset();
    });
}
```

The `||` operator is the `or` operator.  If the first value is falsy, then it will use the second value.  `undefined`, `null`, and a handful of other values qualify as `falsey`, which is a much looser definition that `false.`

Answer (score 1):

`selectedControls || this.controlNames` means "loop over `selectedControls`, but if it is null or undefined loop over `this.controlNames`".

The second argument to `Array.forEach()` is the function to run for each entry in the array, and its parameter is the current item (control) in the array.

Answer (score 1):

The forEach function is used to execute one or more functions once for each value in an array.
For example:

```
function logResult(element) {
console.log(element);
}
//and then performing this operation:
["Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas"].forEach(logResult);
//Would log "Apples", then "Oranges", and then "Bananas" to the console.
```

The handling inside your example is to check whether or not `selectedControls` is defined. If it is, loop over it. If not, loop over `this.controlNames`.

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = ["a", "b", "c"];
a.forEach(function(entry) {
    console.log(entry);
});
```

here forEach take each element of an array  at a time(in every looping)starting from index 0 and print "a" in first loop,"b" in 2nd loop and "c" in 3rd loop.

output in console: a b c

in your code:

```
Array.forEach(selectedControls || this.controlNames, function(control) {
        controls[control].reset();
    });
```

it take `selectedControls`  array or object or `controlNames` array or object(if selectedControls  is null ) and looping through this.`control` is the element of array here which iterate on at a time through each loop.